# Trusty: created desktop shortcuts not available to Dash

Tags: unity, 14.04, unity-dash

On a clean install of Trusty, desktop shortcut files created manually e.g. by Manage Launchers (which worked in Ubuntu Precise) are not found by the Dash even though they are in `/usr/share/applications`. Why is that? For example, the contents of `Magnifier.desktop`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
#ManageLauncher_Version=2.0 beta
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Magnifier
Comment=Virtual Magnifying Glass
Exec=/usr/bin/vmg
Path=/usr/bin/
Icon=/usr/share/magnifier/icon3.png
Categories=Accessibility;
```

PS why is the `#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open` line present when it is not present in any of the standard desktop files (e.g. `evince.desktop`)?